# Layout updates slowly after application becomes active

Tags: ios, swift

My goal is to check the authorization status of `UNUserNotificationCenter` (when the app becomes active again / enters the foreground) and turn a `UISwitch` either on or off, based on the info.

The function works and gets triggered right away but the UISwitch takes 3-5 seconds to update. Is there a better way to update it?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(checkNotificationSettings), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
}

func checkNotificationSettings() {
  self.center.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
    switch settings.authorizationStatus {
    case .authorized:
      self.notificationSwitch.isOn = true
    case .notDetermined, .denied:
      self.notificationSwitch.isOn = false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getNotificationSettings`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649524-getnotificationsettings) basically requests notification settings *asynchronously* so it takes some time until the completion block has been executed.

Apple documentation for the above method also says that the completion block may be executed on a background thread. However, everything that interacts with the UI must be run on the main thread otherwise you'll run into problems similar to what you've encountered in your case.

You should wrap it up with `DispatchQueue.main` to relay UI-related work to main queue and everything should work as expected:

```
self.center.getNotificationSettings { settings in
  DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    self.notificationSwitch.isOn = (settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized)
  }
}
```